# How to make mysql consider the control characters when doing string comparison?

Tags: mysql

In my MySQL settings, the following query returns 1 -

```
SELECT 'data'='dataSOH'
```

Here, the SOH is the "Start of Heading" character with ASCII code 1. My database's default character set is `latin1` and the default collation is `latin1_swedish_ci`. I have tried with several other character sets and collations and every combination gives me 1 as the result of that query. It seems the string comparison ignores the control characters.

Is there any character set and collation that I can use so that this query gives me 0 as its result? Is there any other solution to get it as 0?

MySQL Version I am using: 8.0.30

Comment: @@character_set_database utf8mb4 @@collation_database utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
 https://dbfiddle.uk/CnW8Jmzz

Comment: @P.Salmon *the SOH is the "Start of Heading" character with ASCII code 1*

Comment: @P.Salmon I tried that character set and collation as a first thing and its behavior is the same. Here SOH is "Start of Heading" character with ASCII code 1

Comment: I cannot reproduce. https://dbfiddle.uk/xOscirsq

Comment: @Akina Here it is reproduced - https://dbfiddle.uk/YXcI54FO

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/UHFopXWl For `latin1` character set use `COLLATE latin1_bin`.

Comment: @Akina Yeah, that worked, but I am still in the dark about why it did not work before and why its working with that collation. Do you have any explanation?

Comment: Collation is a rules set for relative chars posession during comparing. According to latin1_swedish_ci the symbol <SOH> is equal to empty string - see https://dbfiddle.uk/Oq6LsU5k. Whereas latin1_bin rule requires to perform the checking not as a set of symbols but as a set of bytes, and you see their difference.