# Why no collation other than 'utf8mb4_0900_bin' can compare strings properly that contains ASCII Control Characters?

Tags: mysql, collation

This question is an extension of the following question - [How to make mysql consider the control characters when doing string comparison?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74299794/how-to-make-mysql-consider-the-control-characters-when-doing-string-comparison)

Here is my query -

```
SELECT 'abc' < 'abcSOH' COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_bin;
```

Here SOH is the Start Of Header which is an ASCII control character with ASCII code 1. My expectation is that this query will return 1 as the second string's length is 4. I have even tried with `Space` (ASCII code 32) with the same results!!

If you check this fiddle, you can see only the 'utf8mb4_0900_bin' collation gives the expected result. All other collations that I have tested give the opposite result.

https://dbfiddle.uk/mDLVWOZG

I have gone through the documentation and could not find the reason behind this. Can anyone please explain why is this?

I am interested to know this because I would like to use a 1-byte character set (and corresponding collation) instead of a 4-byte character set because I have some legacy tables (converting to MySQL) that have a lot of columns and if I use a 4-byte character set, it gives an error that the row is too big.

Comment: Most binary collations treates these control characters equal to CHAR(0) (but utf8mb4_0900_bin). About a space - the literals are treated as variable-length strings whose trailing spaces are removed before compare. For correct comparing you'd use CHARACTER SET binary - in this case the strings are compared as binary strings (byte streams), byte-to-byte. https://dbfiddle.uk/30ijbM4x

Comment: Unfortunately we cant use the binary charset. Is there any other charset and collation combo that just does not ignore an ASCII character?

Comment: *cant use the binary charset.* You can use CONVERT() functon.

Comment: That is not possible in my case, unfortunately. I need a generic solution, not a specific one. All my queries are generated by an engine in a common place. That's why I wanted something like changing the charset and collation. Thanks btw for the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Each *column* can have its own `CHARACTER SET` and `COLLATION`.  But different *rows* must agree.

`CREATE TABLE` provides only "defaults" for those settings -- these defaults are used if you don't override them when declaring the individual columns.

So, legacy columns may as well be declared with whatever antique charset was used.  (Sorry, EBCDIC is not available.)

All the "printable" characters of ASCII are available in UTF-8 (MySQL's utf8/utf8mb3/utf8mb4).  In fact, the binary encoding is identical.

The "control characters" -- well, stick with ascii or latin1 (perhaps with latin1_bin).

Any `_bin` collation says to simply look at the bits.

I do not know if control characters are *turned into* space (hex 20) when `INSERTing` into a UTF-8 column.

Comment: The "control characters" -- well, stick with ascii or latin1 (perhaps with latin1_bin). - Both of those ignore the control characters as well as space.